# Quantum dimension in SU(N) level k Kac-Moody algebra

Tags: conformal-field-theory, kac-moody-algebras

The CFT of the SU(N) level k Kac-Moody current algebra has many Kac-Moody primary fields. I wonder if any one has calculated the quantum dimensions of those Kac-Moody primary fields.

I know that, for SU(2) level k Kac-Moody current algebra, there is a general expression for the quantum dimensions of the SU(2)  primary fields.

Comment: You can use the Kac-Peterson formula for the S-matrix which can be found in Kac book. I don't have the book in front of me but you can find it in eg http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9704003

Comment: See also [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.2292.pdf) (of A. Wassermann) p12, for the more general *twisted* case.

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186348/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a nice database on Web. For example https://www.math.ksu.edu/~gerald/voas/mtc/kmA3_3.html list the data for SU(4) level 3 case.

Comment: The linked page is for SU(4)_3?